# Google Cloud Storage: How make a recursive copy with storage class filter

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

I currently have this command:

```
gsutil -m cp -R gs://myBucket /myDir
```

It copies all the content of a backup to a local directory, with all its objects and directory hierarchy. The problem is that I need to copy only the objects with a "storage class=STARNDAR" or "storage class!=ARCHIVE".

There will be something like:

```
gsutil -m cp -R -cls="STANDARD" gs://myBucket /myDir
```

I need it to be this command, since it is a requirement that the copy be fast and the directory structure be respected.

The only solution I have found so far is to filter beforehand and execute a command per file, which becomes slow and sometimes the execution does not end up showing me "Killed" as a result.

I need it to be this command, since it is a requirement that the copy be fast and the directory structure be respected.